# Can good life experiences make for great life achievements?

Tags: social-psychology

I've been reading about Kurt Cobain's life story and his achievements, and these observations/questions came to mind.

There are plenty of examples of people with unhappy childhoods or life in general that have experienced exceptional professional success later in their life. But is the reverse true as well?

**Can a happy childhood/life make for similar (or even greater) professional success?** Has there been studies whether there's a correlation?